# Defective car or bad windshield repair?

Tags: repair, suzuki, windshield

I have a 2003 suzuki xl7. When my windshield got cracked by a stone on the highway, I had it replaced. It cracked at the corners and I got it replaced again. Same thing happened where cracks came in at the bottom two corners and spread quickly after that.

My mother is convinced that the car is unable to hold its windshield due to damage (people have hit my car when I'm not there, though I don't know why this would affect the windshield). I think they just keep fudging up the installation. I have glass coverage but I wanted to get some ideas quickly as to whether it could actually be a problem with the car's frame or something else that I can't readily assess.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It seems to me the installers aren't putting enough adhesive at the corners of the frame and the glass is touching metal there. This would cause a stress riser at that point and cause the glass to fail. The vehicle would have to flex a large amount for it to crack the glass as you describe.

Comment: I don't think frame damage can be completely discounted, but it would be pretty visible, warped body panels, cracks in the firewall, that kind of thing.

Comment: Good to know. I'll schedule a repair with different people and mention it, hopefully get better results. Good to know it's not likely to be an issue with the car!

Comment: Also look for rusty spots. Blooming rust can crack a windshield!